# Using random number draws to repopulate an array for analysis

Tags: arrays, excel, random, vba

I'm trying to create a subroutine to perform an analysis.

**UPDATE**: The error the sub generates is as follows: Run-time error '424' - object required

There are two declared ranges. I want to randomly draw three of the values from the results range, perform returns analysis, and pass this result to one cell of the results range. I then want to repeat this until the second, larger range is populated with this random draw analysis.This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub boostrap()

Dim returns As Variant
Dim Results As Variant
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim ret As Variant

Dim firstrow As Variant, lastrow As Variant
Dim annualised_return As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long


returns = Range("returns")
Results = Range("Results")
n = Range("returns").count
m = Range("Results").count

lastrow = Range("returns").End(xlDown).Row
firstrow = Range("returns").Row


For j = 1 To m

        ReDim draw(1 To 3) 'to create a draw reference number from the second range
            draw(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(firstrow, lastrow)
            draw(2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(firstrow, lastrow)
            draw(3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(firstrow, lastrow)

    ReDim ret(1 To 3)
        ret(1) = returns(draw(1).Value)
        ret(2) = returns(draw(2).Value)
        ret(3) = returns(draw(3).Value)




 Results(j) =  (((1 + ret(1)) * (1 + ret(2)) * (1 + ret(3))) ^ (1 / 3) - 1)
Next j

End Sub
```

Stepping through the sub, the error seems to stem from when i try and pass the numbers from the draw as a reference to the results range. i.e if the draw produces #22, then i want to select the value in row 22 to be placed in the array of results, which i will then analyse (along with the other two draws) to populate each cell of the results range.

Can anyone provide assistance on how to remedy this? 
Muchos thanks

Comment: Explain precisely what is the problem. Are you getting an error message or does the code just not do what you want? Have you tried stepping through the code? You should declare `returns` and `Results` as ranges, and use `Set` to assign the variables.

Comment: Do you need to be inputting a range here? Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(firstrow, lastrow), for instance, should this be Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(.range("A" & irstrow).address, .range("A" & lastrow).address),

Comment: @Lowpar - I had to look up the function, but it just needs a lower and upper limit so I think that bit is fine.

Comment: You can't put two equals on the same line: `Results(j) = annualised_return = (((1 ...`

Comment: At least, not like that. You could if you wanted to set a `Boolean` value. E.g. `myBool = (a = b)` (sets `myBool` to `True` if `a` = `b`).

Comment: `returns` is fine to have as a `Variant` in your case, but you will need to `Set` `Results` to be a `Range` if you want it to output it to your worksheet. As it is, it will just store the values in a variant array.

Comment: @SteveES. Good spot on the double = I hadn't noticed that as the error occurs before then.

Comment: @SJR the error i get is a "run-time error 424 - object required". This occurs when the sub goes to populate the ret array.

Comment: @Chronicles.84 You never declare `draw` anywhere. You should use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to catch these errors. It will be a `Variant` by default and therefore not have a `.Value` property.

Comment: @Chronicles.84 You should edit your question to say what and where the error occurs (i.e. what you say in the comment).

Comment: @SteveES - feedback noted. I've amended it to declare the draw, and option explicit. However, if i try to declare draw as a range, the redim of draw produces:' compile error' - array expected. is there no way for an array to have the .value property?

Comment: Can you try this? `ret(1) = returns(draw(1),1)`? Am assuming the range Returns is a single column (which means the array is automatically 2D).

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code, some of which you would have found yourself if you had used `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module.

Firstly, the error is being caused by the statement:

```
returns(draw(1).Value)
```

`draw` is not declared anywhere, so will be of type `Variant` by default; `Variant, Integer` after the call to `RandBetween()`. Therefore, it doesn't have a `.Value` property (or any methods or properties for that matter), so calling draw(1).Value raises the error. You should declare `draw` as an `Integer` array:

```
Dim draw() As Integer      'or
Dim draw(1 To 3) As Integer    'Better if always (1 To 3), then you don't need to ReDim
```

Then you don't need the `.Value`, just use:

```
ret(1) = returns(draw(1),1)
```

Note that `returns` is a 2D Variant array due to you assigning it with `Range` values. When you do `Variant = Range().Value`, it always makes a 2D array, even if the `Range` is only one cell.

Secondly, if you want to use your `Results` variable to output data to your worksheet, you need to declare it as a `Range` variable and `Set` it, e.g.

```
Dim Results As Range
Set Results = myWorkbook.myWorksheet.Range("Results")
```

I have added `myWorkbook` and `myWorksheet` because you should also fully qualify your references in order to avoid errors.

Thirdly, this line:

```
Results(j) = annualised_return = (((1 + ret(1)) * (1 + ret(2)) * (1 + ret(3))) ^ (1 / 3) - 1)
```

will test whether `annualised_return` is equal to `(((1 + ret(1)) * (1 + ret(2)) * (1 + ret(3))) ^ (1 / 3) - 1)`, and set `Results(j)` equal to the `True`/`False` outcome of this test. I assume this is not what you wanted.

Finally, a smaller piece of general advice: explicitly declare all of your variables and avoid declaring variables as `Variant` unless there is a good reason for it. E.g. `firstrow` and `lastrow` could both be of type `Long`. It will help avoid errors and `Variant` variables are less efficient.

Comment: I had used option explicit at the start, but, it still looks like I have a bit to learn about how the intricacies of declaring properly. Thank you for feedback, I will try to take this all on board.